# Disable specific notice in PHP

Tags: php, output, e-notices

I want to be able to define some custom constants using `define` locally which are later redeclared in the code, so the program throws `Notice: Constant MY_CONSTANT already defined in...`.

This is for development purposes, so I want to hide that notice without hiding other notices.

If I use `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` all notices would be disabled in development, which I don't want.

How can I disable only the constant already defined notices?

If it's not possible, is there any way to overwrite a constant that's declared somewhere else in the code? Currently I do it by defining my desired value before the existing one is declared, so it would use the value I set (but this shows the notices).

Comment: _"How can I disable only the constant already defined notices?"_ - only by implementing your own error handler, that would then specifically filter out those notices ...

Comment: _"is there any way to overwrite a constant that's declared somewhere else in the code?"_ - of course there isn't, that would totally defeat the purpose of a constant. Could at most be done the other way around - that second, "later" location in the code, would have to check with `defined()` first, whether the constant is already set at this point, and only set it when not.

Comment: @CBroe I don't have access to that later location in the code, so the only solution I found was to define my constant first, which would indeed "overwrite" (not set) the initial value. The only issue I noticed are the notices.

Comment: Why can't you just use a different name for your constant? Is there a reason specifically you need to override the value of the existing one? When you say you "don't have access to it" does that mean it's in some 3rd party code which you'd rather not change? Why do you want to override its defined behaviour then? The underlying purpose of this is vague in your question, but you seem to be trying to fight the way php is intended to work, and it's not really clear why.

Comment: @ADyson I don't think the reason is relevant, but the main idea is that I want to easily override constants for local development without changing code in the versioned files or using env variables.

Comment: The reason is relevant because it sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need to test what would happen if the constant was different, if you wouldn't change it in production? But if you really do need that, then simply change the constant in the place where it's defined. When you're finished, revert it back. If you're using source control properly it ought to be easy enough to keep track of (in a branch?). Or just make careful notes. Better than trying to find some bizarre workaround to a fundamental language behaviour. Also unclear why you want to avoid env variables.

Comment: @ADyson I am just working on a quick project, I need the quickest solution that works. If I keep changing/reverting the constants for dev/production, it wastes too much time. Using environment variables in PHP has a performance overhead that has to be considered for high traffic too (which is the case for this project).

Comment: The quickest solution that works _is_ changing the constants in the code. We've already explained, I think, why there aren't really any viable alternatives. What you're doing doesn't appear to make a lot of sense still